# Error in code while converting infix form to prefix form using stack class

Tags: python

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.stack=[]
        self.top = None

    def empty(self):
        return not self.stack

    def push(self, item):
        self.stack.append(item)
        self.top = item

    def pop(self):
        if self.empty():
            a = self.stack.pop()
            return a
        else:
            print("Empty stack")
    
    def printall(self):
        print(self.stack)
    
    def clear(self):
        self.stack = []
        self.top = None

ysj = Stack()
jy = []

list = input().split()
leng = len(list)

num = 0

for i in range(0, leng):
    if list[i] == '+' or list[i] == '-':
        while ysj.top is not None:
            jy.append(ysj.pop())
            num = num - 1
        ysj.push(list[i])
        num = num + 1

    elif list[i] == '/' or list[i] == '*':
        while ysj.top == '/' or ysj.top == '*':
            jy.append(ysj.pop())
            num = num - 1
        ysj.push(list[i])
        num = num + 1

    else:
        jy.append(int(list[i]))

for i in range(1, num + 1):
    jy.append(ysj.pop())

for i in range(0, len(jy)):
    print(jy[i], end=" ")
```

I'm trying to convert the equation from infix form to postfix form using Stack class.

This code works when I type in
1 + 2 * 3

but doesn't work well when I type in

1 * 2 + 3 or 1 * 2 * 3 or 1 + 2 + 3

I think there's something wrong with my while loop but I can't figure out what part is wrong. Please help me.

Comment: `Stack.empty` looks weird: apparently, the stack is _not_ empty when `self.stack==None`, but _is_ empty in any other case? You never set `self.stack` to `None`, so this method will say that the stack is _always_ empty.

Comment: To check for an empty stack a simple `return not self.stack` would be enough.

Comment: I edited the def empty part but it still doesn't work when I type the last 3 cases in... It just spits out 'Empty stack' countlessly. Do you know why this doesn't work?

Comment: Could you give more details? Which input should produce which output? The bad naming of the variables doesn't help analyzing the code. What does `ysj` represent? And what is `jy`?

Comment: ysj is a stack to put the arithmetic operation symbols in, and jy is the list that keeps the result for the conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to insert `None` to `top` when the list gets empty, and you are trying to remove a item when the list is empty:

```
class Stack:
      def __init__(self):
          self.stack=[]
          self.top = None
  
      def empty(self):
          return not self.stack
  
      def push(self, item):
          self.stack.append(item)
          self.top = item
  
      def pop(self):
          if not self.empty(): # remove item only if the stack is not empty
              a = self.stack.pop()
              # after removing a item, check if the stack is empty
              if self.empty(): # if it is, set the top as None
                  self.top = None
              return a 
          else:
              print("Empty stack")
```